# reactJS sending a Form via Post to a REST API returns NULL

Tags: rest, reactjs, fetch

I want to send some Data with Fetch to my REST Backend (written in Playframework). The Rest Route exists and works.

Now I want to send my Form inputs to the backend.

My form looks like this:

```
<form idName="newForm" method="POST" action="" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <Input type='text' required label={<T value="processes.new.inputTitle"/>} name='title' value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'title')} maxLength={16}/>
```

My handleSubmit looks like this:

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log("Formular abgesendet");

    var newProcess = {
        a: document.getElementsByName('title').value,
        b: document.getElementsByName('responsible').value
    };

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append( "json", JSON.stringify( newProcess ) );

    fetch('http://localhost:9000/process', {
        method: 'post',
        body: data
    });
}
```

The function is called, the console Log works. But only Null is sent to backend....

Whats my failure?

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('title')` return an array, maybe you should try with `document.getElementsByName('title')[0].value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElement**s**ByName` returns `NodeList` Collection that doesn't have `value` property.

If you are sure there is only one element with this name

```
var newProcess = {
    a: document.getElementsByName('title')[0].value,
    b: document.getElementsByName('responsible')[0].value
}
```

or

```
var newProcess = {
    a: document.querySelector('[name=title]').value,
    b: document.querySelector('[name=responsible]').value
}
```

Comment: is there a smarter way to map  the form into a json?

Comment: @Felix. Yes, google for "react controlled input" https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Comment: @Felix Since you are using react I do recommend you to go @oliv37 way other than manually accessing the DOM. `handleChange` should keep form' state up to date with inputs.  So you could simply use `this.state.title` w/o querying the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Your input seems to be controlled by React (You specified `value` and `onChange` attributes) so you can simply use the state to build the request body

```
var newProcess = {
    a: this.state.title,
    b: this.state.responsible
};
```